# How to change the title of submit button when someone register in mailchimp?

Tags: forms, emails

I want to be able to change the title of the submit button of the [Mailchimp](https://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) block when someone subscribes or unsubscribes to mail chimp list. I'm using mailchimp block on D7.
How shall I do it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you'll want to use hook_form_alter(). You can check if the user has subscribed with mailchimp_is_subscribed() and change the submit button text accordingly.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'mailchimp_lists_user_subscribe_form_test') {
    global $user;
    // First parameter is the list id, which can be found here:
    // https://polkaspots.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201070513-Where-can-I-find-my-MailChimp-API-key-and-List-ID
    $form['submit']['#value'] = mailchimp_is_subscribed('123abc', $user->mail) ? t('Unregister') : t('Register');
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a short code example of how you might do that?

Comment: Sure, hope it helps! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `hook_form_alter()` hook or install the [string overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module if you don't wish to write any code.

Comment: I want to change it after submitting the form. The title right now is register so when someone registers i want it to get changed to unregister.